# Create camera app using react native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

Is it possible to make a camera app using Expo so that the camera will be opened right after I start the app. The solution I found needs to tap a button 'start camera' after the app is started. But I want my app to open camera without pressing any buttons (right like the native camera app on iOS)

Comment: Best to share your current solution for us to take a look but even the following package may be what you are looking for.   At a quick glance, it seems like it allows you to start the camera programmatically: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: expo-cam does allow that https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/ as well as the one mentioned by @AleksandarZoric https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera should work too